# What makes workbooks.cancheckout fail?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Here's the short version... let me know if any additional information can help.

I have an Excel document on SharePoint. I have two users who both are in the same security group and both have contribute access to the document.

On one user, `workbooks.cancheckout("http://address/document")` returns true as long as nobody else has it checked out.  As designed.

With another user, `workbooks.cancheckout("http://address/document")` returns false.  All the time.

The user CAN check the document out directly from SharePoint, so this is NOT a permissions issue.  I believe it has something to do with the way Excel is trying to talk to SharePoint.

What causes "cancheckout" to return false, and does anyone have any suggestions on what is causing or how to fix this error?

The working user is using Office 2010.  The broken one is 2013.  However, several other users, all on 2013, are not having the error.  OS is Windows 7 for all users.

Comment: What version of SP? Also, is it SP Online or on-prem? What authentication method is being used for SP?

Comment: 2010, on-premesis, and SSO (active directory).  Also, the issue seems to be sporadic, as it didn't occur toward the end of last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has similar issue. I asked user to manually access share point portal document from their desktop and then use excel VBA program. It works.  if you change password then you have to manually go to share point and access that document so your credentials are stored somewhere in cache.  It is wired but this is they way I resolved problem faced by one of my user.

Comment: I'll inquire about recent password changes.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @thePolarExpress88 - Hi, I'm facing the same problem and tried your solution but no luck. Can you please help me sort out this issue?