# .CanCheckOut not returning the correct value?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, checkout

I am trying to check if a file, stored on a SharePoint server, can be checked out or not so I can alert the user and stop them from editing the workbook without checking out the file. I have tried the code below but when I try to run it, it believes it is not possible to check out and doesn't do anything. Yet when I check the SharePoint server it says that it is not checked out and can be checked out.

```
Function CheckOutCheck2() As Boolean
'CheckOutCheck2 = True
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("FilePath") = True Then
    MsgBox "Please make sure the workbook is checkout before making any changes", vbInformation, "Check Out"
    CheckOutCheck2 = True
    Debug.Print ("Can Check Out")
End If
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("Filepath") = False Then
    CheckOutCheck2 = False
    Debug.Print ("Cant Check Out")
End If
End Function
```

and when I click my button I do this:

```
If CheckOutCheck2() = True Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    CreateNew.Show
End If
```

I want to be able to stop the user from doing anything until the file is checked out.

Anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you see this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330499/checkout-workbook-in-vba Does it apply? Or maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145177/what-makes-workbooks-cancheckout-fail ?

Comment: @Ralph. Thanks for those links, I think I missed them when I did a search. anyway the first link is very similar to what my issue is and to over come it I am now checking if the file can be checked in instead, and it seems to be working. Thanks once again for the links. :)